# AVPlayer not able to playing Live Radio URL

Tags: ios, avplayer

My Live Radio URL is http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream and AVPlayer not able to play.

It's Live Radio Audio.

And it's my code.

```
@interface ViewController () {
    AVPlayer *player;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:true error:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    AVPlayer *player123 = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream"]];
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = true;
    player = player123;
}

- (IBAction)btnPayPauseAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    if (sender.selected) {
        [player play];
    } else {
        [player pause];
    }
}
@end
```

The error is :

```
Task <70641693-CCCD-43C1-8A18-13A853FA3CD3>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://s2.yesstreaming.net:7091/stream, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <70641693-CCCD-43C1-8A18-13A853FA3CD3>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <70641693-CCCD-43C1-8A18-13A853FA3CD3>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access the data of AVPlayer when playing video from HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592561/access-the-data-of-avplayer-when-playing-video-from-http-live-streaming)

Comment: It's not duplicate of this. And also not saved it on locally.

Comment: Maybe it is; maybe it is not. I can't tell what you are doing or attempting as the code is not here to see. Very difficult to provide answers if you don't provide information.

Comment: @impression7vx sir, it's my code.

Comment: Where do you declare your player object? Inside a function or inside a class? Which scope?

Comment: @impression7vx sir, it's my simple code.

Comment: you may be in the need of tell streaming file extension too.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan it's from Icecast

Comment: then why don't you use RadioKit ?

Comment: check an answer over here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830464/ios-online-radio-streaming-questions

Comment: I believe the stream delivers `application/ogg` and AVPlayer does not have builtin support for this. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804046/playing-an-ogg-stream-in-ios